# ServiceStack - Upload files with stream and with Uri

Tags: servicestack

I have got the following DTOs:

```
[Route("/images/{imageId}/upload", "PUT")]
public class GetImageWithStream : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
    public string imageId { get; set; }
}

///images/{imageId}/upload?url={imageUrl}
[Route("/images/{imageId}/upload", "PUT")]
public class GetImageWithUri 
{
    public string imageId { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

/images/1/upload  -> this should routed to the first DTO

/images/1/upload?url=something.jpg  -> this should routed to the second DTO

Now both of them routed to the first DTO and in case of the second path the stream is a NullStream of course. With the first path the stream is good but the imageId is null.

Or I can imagine something like this:

```
[Route("/images/{imageId}/upload", "PUT")]
public class GetImageWithStream : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
    public string imageId { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to handle the same PATH with different ways in ServiceStack?

Answer (score 2):

Using a `IRequiresRequestStream` tells ServiceStack to skip the Request Binding and to let your Service read from the un-buffered request stream.

But if you just want to [handle file uploads](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#uploading-files) you can access uploaded files independently of the Request DTO using `RequestContext.Files`. e.g:

```
public object Post(MyFileUpload request)
{
    if (this.Request.Files.Length > 0)
    {
        var uploadedFile = this.Request.Files[0];
        uploadedFile.SaveTo(MyUploadsDirPath.CombineWith(file.FileName));
    }
    return HttpResult.Redirect("/");
}
```

ServiceStack's [imgur.servicestack.net](http://imgur.servicestack.net) example shows how to access the [byte stream of multiple uploaded files](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/ImageResizer/Global.asax.cs#L63), e.g:

```
public object Post(Upload request)
{
    foreach (var uploadedFile in Request.Files
       .Where(uploadedFile => uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            uploadedFile.WriteTo(ms);
            WriteImage(ms);
        }
    }
    return HttpResult.Redirect("/");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine but only with POST methods. If I set the verb to PUT the Files contains no element.