# ServiceStack - upload files as byte stream?

Tags: http, servicestack, http-upload

I am trying to create my own S3 compatible server using self-hosted ServiceStack (version 4.0.31 on mono) and I need to support s3curl.pl format uploads.  The problem is that they do not use mutipart uploads but appear to use the default http binary format.  I already have ServiceStack working for multipart/form-data uploads.  I have also looked at all applicable posts on related topics and none of them work for me.  For example: [ServiceStack - Upload files with stream and with Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311733/servicestack-upload-files-with-stream-and-with-uri)  looked like it would address my problem.  The problem is that I can't resolve RequestContext.Files for that solution.

Here is my curl command line (note that the Auth is bogus so it is not a security risk):

```
curl -H 'Date: Thu, 09 Oct 2014 16:56:21 +0000' -H 'Authorization: AWS Y29tZXQ=:ciitxdxRvWrlcVsc48JnXqKu/oY=' -L -H 'content-type: ' -T README.txt 'http://localhost:1301/s3/README.txt?format=xml' -k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `base.Request.Files` API is only for handling HTTP `multipart/form-data` file uploads.

To handle other File Uploads you can decorate your Request DTO with `IRequiresRequestStream` which tells ServiceStack to skip deserialization and inject the Raw InputStream into your DTO instead:

```
public class RawFileUpload : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

In your Service you can handle

```
public class UploadServices : Service
{
    public object Any(RawFileUpload request)
    {
        var filePath = "~/uploads/{0}".Fmt(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"))
                       .MapAbsolutePath();
        using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        {
            request.RequestStream.WriteTo(fs);
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

This feature is described in the [Serialization/Deserialization wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream).

Comment: Thanks, that works! Is it possible to combine a route with a Stream, or are they mutually exclusive?  I tried keeping other vars in the DTO but the values came in null.The S3 URI format is /mybucket/photos/2014/08/puppy.jpg?x-foo=bar and I guess I'll have to pull the fields out of the Request.RawUrl myself if I can't do the upload and route extraction at the same time via the DTO?  - BTW, I am a big fan of ServiceStack and I'm architecting a major product with it right now.

Comment: @tradetree wasn't before, you'd need to pull values from `base.Request` but I've just [added support for it in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/bc3492b20a6ace58dd88539fe5114e647f5f830e). This change is now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Ok, good to know.  I hope to stick to mature versions for the stability of our development, but glad to hear it will be there for the future.